# For Each Loop in Laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach

I have below database structure in my `driver_location table`

[image]

From this table I am fetching near-by driver id who are within 5 km distance and status equal online with below query in laravel

```
 $nearest_car = DriverLocation::select(DB::raw('*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$pickup_latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos(radians( longitude ) - radians('.$pickup_longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$pickup_latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) as distance'))
->having('distance', '<=', 5)->where('driver_location.status','Online')->where('driver_location.car_id',$car_id);
```

Now what I want to do is for each near by user_id from `driver_location` table a request will be inserted in `bid_request` table limited to 5 nearby drivers. I have tried with a for loop like below but it is inserting record for same user_id from driver location table multiple times. I need one request for each user

```
 for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    DB::table('bid_request')->insert(
    array(
        'user_id'     =>   $rider_id, 
        'group_id'   =>   null,
         'pickup_latitude'     => $pickup_latitude, 
        'pickup_longitude'   =>   $pickup_longitude,
         'drop_latitude'     =>   $drop_latitude, 
        'drop_longitude'   =>    $drop_longitude,
         'driver_id'     =>   $nearest_car->user_id, 
        'car_id'   =>   $car_id,
         'pickup_location'     =>   $pickup_location, 
        'drop_location'   =>    $drop_location,
         'payment_mode'     =>   $payment_method_store, 
        'status'   =>   'Pending',
         'is_wallet'     =>    $is_wallet, 
        'driver_mobile'   =>    $driver_details->mobile_number,
         'driver_avg_ratings'     =>   $driver_details->driver_avg_ratings, 

        'distance'   =>   $dis,
        'min_time'   =>   $get_near_car_time

        //minimum time and distance needs to b
       )
     );

    }
 }// end $is_wallet!='Bid'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to insert 5 record in bid_request table than get only 5 record from below query:

```
$nearest_car = DriverLocation::select(DB::raw('*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$pickup_latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos(radians( longitude ) - radians('.$pickup_longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$pickup_latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) as distance'))
->having('distance', '<=', 5)
->where('driver_location.status','Online')
->where('driver_location.car_id',$car_id)
->limit(5)->get();
```

Now you need to array of records to insert in table :

```
$data = [];
foreach ($nearest_car as $key => $value) {
  $data[] = [
    'user_id'     =>   $rider_id,
    'group_id'   =>   null,
    'pickup_latitude'     => $pickup_latitude,
    'pickup_longitude'   =>   $pickup_longitude,
    'drop_latitude'     =>   $drop_latitude,
    'drop_longitude'   =>    $drop_longitude,
    'driver_id'     =>   $value->user_id,
    'car_id'   =>   $car_id,
    'pickup_location'     =>   $pickup_location,
    'drop_location'   =>    $drop_location,
    'payment_mode'     =>   $payment_method_store,
    'status'   =>   'Pending',
    'is_wallet'     =>    $is_wallet,
    'driver_mobile'   =>    $driver_details->mobile_number,
    'driver_avg_ratings'     =>   $driver_details->driver_avg_ratings,
    'distance'   =>   $dis,
    'min_time'   =>   $get_near_car_time
  ];
}
```

Insert in table :

```
DB::table('bid_request')->insert($data);
```

Comment: Thanks its working like a charm. Can it be a performance issue when so many users will use the same?

Comment: :) Not a big issue, bcz for record insert it will execute only one query. if records are too large than may take time in for loop but records will inserted in bunch

Comment: one issue, driver_avg_ratings is being inserted from users table which is different for every driver but it is inserting same value taken as the first driver ratings for all

Comment: in foreach loop we use $value variable , so you can use using it. for reference what i have did in  driver_id :     'driver_id'     =>   $value->user_id,

Comment: when I am using this  'driver_avg_ratings'     => $value->$driver_details->driver_avg_ratings, it is not inserting any data

Comment: do you have driver_avg_ratings in driver_location table ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204168/discussion-between-yasin-patel-and-mithu).

Answer (score 0):

To access this in your view you wil have to do something like this:

```
@foreach ($text as $demo)
<p>This my product name {{ $demo->name }}</p>
<p>This my product category {{ $demo->category->name}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

using **Forloop** you should specify `$i` in variable.

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    DB::table('bid_request')->insert(
        'user_id'     =>   $rider_id[$i], 
        'group_id'   =>   null,
         'pickup_latitude'     => $pickup_latitude, 
        'pickup_longitude'   =>   $pickup_longitude,
         'drop_latitude'     =>   $drop_latitude, 
        'drop_longitude'   =>    $drop_longitude,
         'driver_id'     =>   $nearest_car->user_id, 
        'car_id'   =>   $car_id,
         'pickup_location'     =>   $pickup_location, 
        'drop_location'   =>    $drop_location,
         'payment_mode'     =>   $payment_method_store, 
        'status'   =>   'Pending',
         'is_wallet'     =>    $is_wallet, 
        'driver_mobile'   =>    $driver_details->mobile_number,
         'driver_avg_ratings'     =>   $driver_details->driver_avg_ratings, 

        'distance'   =>   $dis,
        'min_time'   =>   $get_near_car_time

        //minimum time and distance needs to b
     );
    }
 }
```

And if you are use **ForEach** loop:

```
foreach($variable_which_contains_all_values as $value){
        DB::table('bid_request')->insert(
            'user_id'     =>   $value->rider_id, 
            'group_id'   =>   null,
             'pickup_latitude'     => $pickup_latitude, 
            'pickup_longitude'   =>   $pickup_longitude,
             'drop_latitude'     =>   $drop_latitude, 
            'drop_longitude'   =>    $drop_longitude,
             'driver_id'     =>   $nearest_car->user_id, 
            'car_id'   =>   $car_id,
             'pickup_location'     =>   $pickup_location, 
            'drop_location'   =>    $drop_location,
             'payment_mode'     =>   $payment_method_store, 
            'status'   =>   'Pending',
             'is_wallet'     =>    $is_wallet, 
            'driver_mobile'   =>    $driver_details->mobile_number,
             'driver_avg_ratings'     =>   $driver_details->driver_avg_ratings, 

            'distance'   =>   $dis,
            'min_time'   =>   $get_near_car_time

            //minimum time and distance needs to b
         );

        }
     }
```